# Disable mysql rollback with jdbc and setAutoCommit(false) on connection close

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, rollback, autocommit

I am learning how to use mysql in Java so I've been using Connector/J as my jdbc driver.  I noticed that when I set conn.setAutoCommit(false), even if I only use a `SELECT` statement, when the connection is closed, a rollback is issued and I would like to disable that.  I have tried the following connection properties but none of them helped:

`connectionProps.put("useLocalSessionState", "true");
connectionProps.put("useLocalTransactionState", "true");
connectionProps.put("rollbackOnPooledClose", "false");`

I figure that the last property doesn't work because I am not using a pooled connection.  I have also tried setting the connection to read only by using a read only user in the connection and by setting `conn.setReadOnly(true)` but this did not help.

EDIT:  To clarify, rollbacks on connection close are unnecessary because I will either be querying the database or I will issue a `commit()` before the connection is closed.

Comment: *"when the connection is closed, a rollback is issued and I would like to disable that"* - Please [edit] your question to explain why you want to do that. In other words, please describe the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't give you a better reason besides the fact that the rollback is superfluous given the fact that I will always ensure that I issue a `commit()` before closing a connection unless I am querying the database.  I will update this question to try and reflect this.